# Max value in pandas based on descending windows

Tags: pandas, group-by, max, sliding

i have some experience with pandas - but cannot figure out the following:
i have several weeks of timestamped data with multiple records within one day,
i want to add a column in which, for each day, the maximum value of the remaining records of that day is displayed.
so if 5 records remain in a particular day, i need the max the next 5 records, after that, the max of next 4 records etc etc.

I have tried to use Group By but this does not seem to do the trick,
can somebody help me out?

[exampledata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3seG.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fastest, but you can try this -

```
dt['mvalue'] = dt.sort('datetime', ascending=False).groupby('date').value.cummax()
```

It simply does rolling max on a reverse sorted series